# SimpleXML - how can I list attributes of a random list of children?

Tags: php, attributes, simplexml, children

I've got some xml that has mutiple children. Their names are known, quantity and order are not.
In this case they can be FreeRide or SteadyState.

I need to preserve their order and then extract the attributes of Duration and Power.

```
<?php
$xml='<workout_file>
    <workout>
       <FreeRide Duration="300" Power="1.3"/>
        <SteadyState Duration="300" Power="0.55"/>
        <FreeRide Duration="10"  Power="1.2"/>
        <SteadyState Duration="180" Power="0.55"/>
        <FreeRide Duration="10"  Power="1.1"/>
        <SteadyState Duration="120" Power="0.55"/>
    </workout>
</workout_file>';

$xml=simplexml_load_string($xml);

$count = 0;
foreach($xml->workout->children() as $node ){
    $type = $node->getName();
    echo $type." position: ".$count."<br>";
    $count++;

    //Get Attributes
    //$attr =  $xml->workout->$$type[$count]->attributes(); //Doesn't work Undefined variable: FreeRide
    //echo "Duration: ".$attr['Duration']."<br>";
    //echo "Power: ".$attr['Power']."<br>";
}
```

I can list the children, along with their position using this code.
However I'm not sure how to get the attributes, since the exact child name is not known (they can be in any order).

Note: This lists FreeRide children only:
$attr =  $xml->workout->FreeRide[$count]->attributes();

How can I get a list of children, Duration and Power, in correct order?

Comment: Thanks to Rob Ruchte, solution works for me

Comment: Thanks IMSoP, that seems to work well too, with fewer lines of code. Good to know about the DOM method too, may come in handy.

Answer (score 1):

This is a great case for using [DOM](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) instead of SimpleXML. In all but the most basic cases, SimpleXML is usually more difficult to use than DOM in my experience.

```
<?php
$xml='<workout_file>
    <workout>
       <FreeRide Duration="300" Power="1.3"/>
        <SteadyState Duration="300" Power="0.55"/>
        <FreeRide Duration="10"  Power="1.2"/>
        <SteadyState Duration="180" Power="0.55"/>
        <FreeRide Duration="10"  Power="1.1"/>
        <SteadyState Duration="120" Power="0.55"/>
    </workout>
</workout_file>';

//Instantiate a DOMDocument and load our XML
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml);

// Instantiate DOMXpath with our document
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

//Get all of our workout elements and iterate through them
$workoutElements = $xpath->query('/workout_file/workout');
foreach($workoutElements as $currElement)
{
    //Iterate through the children
    $count = 0;
    foreach($currElement->childNodes as $currIntervalNode)
    {
        /*
         * Since we're going through ALL of the children, some of them will be whitespace nodes we don't care about,
         * so only look at nodes with attributes
         */
        if($currIntervalNode->hasAttributes())
        {
            // the nodeName attribute is the tag name
            $type = $currIntervalNode->nodeName;

            // Pull out the attribute vaules by name
            $duration = $currIntervalNode->getAttribute('Duration');
            $power = $currIntervalNode->getAttribute('Power');

            echo 'Position: '.$count++.'<br>'.PHP_EOL;
            echo 'Type: '.$type.'<br>'.PHP_EOL;
            echo 'Duration: '.$duration.'<br>'.PHP_EOL;
            echo 'Power: '.$power.'<br>'.PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is really no need for DOM here; the OP already had the `foreach` loop working, and just needed the attributes of their `$node` variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are over-thinking this. You have a variable representing an XML node, and you want the attributes of that node. That's as simple as this:

```
//Get Attributes
echo "Duration: ".$node['Duration']."<br>";
echo "Power: ".$node['Power']."<br>";
```

(You only need to call `->attributes()` explicitly if you are dealing with namespaces, or if you want to loop over all the attributes of a node, neither of which apply in this case.)

So in total:

```
<?php
$xml='<workout_file>
    <workout>
       <FreeRide Duration="300" Power="1.3"/>
        <SteadyState Duration="300" Power="0.55"/>
        <FreeRide Duration="10"  Power="1.2"/>
        <SteadyState Duration="180" Power="0.55"/>
        <FreeRide Duration="10"  Power="1.1"/>
        <SteadyState Duration="120" Power="0.55"/>
    </workout>
</workout_file>';

$xml=simplexml_load_string($xml);

$count = 0;
foreach($xml->workout->children() as $node ){
    $type = $node->getName();
    echo $type." position: ".$count."<br>";
    $count++;

    //Get Attributes
    echo "Duration: ".$node['Duration']."<br>";
    echo "Power: ".$node['Power']."<br>";
}
```

[Live demo](https://3v4l.org/MKUEZ)